# Wordpress protected Pages

Tags: pages, password

Would be possible to access the protected pages with password through of a token. What I mean I pass the token by URL, is going to be checked if the page is protected, if yes check if the URL has the token than the token to be check if match or not.

Comment: What are you asking? I don't understand a single word....

Comment: Let me try to translate :) "I'd like to set some of my posts to 'protected' but still allow access using a nonce-like passcode in the `$_GET` string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protected post system uses `POST` so by default, no you can't. However, here is a bare-bone mechanism that will let you do this.

```
function bypass_protected_post() {
  if (is_single()) {
    global $post,$_GET;
    if (isset($post->post_password)) {
      $bypasskey = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bypasskey', true);
      if (isset($_GET['bypasskey']) && $_GET['bypasskey'] == $bypasskey) {
        $post->post_password = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_head','bypass_protected_post');
```

You need to set the `bypasskey` value for the post using the normal custom meta fields form. You'd access the protected post by tacking `?bypasskey=<whatever>` onto the URL. Place this in your theme's `functions.php` and you are good to go.

Consider this a sort-of proof-of-concept. I don't think I'd implement it exactly as it is. I'd probably put it in a plugin and use one-time keys or keys with a limited lifespan-- say two or three days. And maybe include a random key generator.

Comment: thanks a lot,lot.  Anyway I wanted to limit the lifespan of each login session. Let me give a try and I'm going to give a feedback soon.