# Put password on a wordpress link in a article

Tags: links, password

I've trying to find out how to do this in wordpress and I've searched the web, but I can't find any easy way to make my visitor only see one link if they enter a password to be able to see it.

Is there any plugin or solution that could do that ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72993/21376 ?

Comment: Yeah I need something similar, but I want to put the password only to a specific link in the text of my wordpress article. Such as something with a input field neaby, and by entering the password, the link is made available

Comment: Sorry, still not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is almost what the article [Add Private Content to Posts via Shortcode](http://digwp.com/2010/05/private-content-posts-shortcode/) talks about. But it's only for registered users:

```
add_shortcode('private', 'private_content');
function private_content($atts, $content = null) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        return '<div class="private-content">' . $content . '</div>';
    return '';
}
```

And used inside the post/page like:

> [private]
>   This post contains registered-only content!
>   [/private]

To add a password functionality, you'd have to add a `<form>` inside the shortcode function and show the content after the password is successfully `$_POST`ed.
Maybe it's more straight forward [using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498959/how-to-use-ajax-in-a-wordpress-shortcode).